# how to customise the wordpress description

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

Hi everyone would like to ask if it is possible to customise the WordPress description.

For example on my local site the description is Blah | Blah | Blah

Is it possible to have each "blah" a different colour using code or would I be have to write out a new block of code instead of using

```
 <?php bloginfo('description');?>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting html in the description field?

Comment: Yes but I put them all in ' ' is that wrong, should I try and add the html in the brackets without the ' ' ?

and thanks for such a quick response :)

Comment: I just tried on my wordpress install and it just throws the html as text to the page. if you put html in your description field and follow the instructions in the answer below you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use html code in the description(which will have classes to style) and display it using this:

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description')); ?>
```

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/allowing-html-tags-in-the-site-description-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you so much for your post James could you give me an example as to where you would add the html code once you add that line ?

Comment: bloginfo('description') pulls the information that you type in the Tagline field that is located in the Wordpress backend, Settings->General. Add the html there such as: <span class="first">blah</span> | <span class="second">blah</span> | <span class="third">blah</span> and then style it through CSS.

Comment: Hey James THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH ! Really appreciate it, tried it out and it works. Wasn't sure if it was even possible. You have made my work load  easier.